# Field theory, Abel-Ruffini theorem, technical question

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras

Let me put the question first.

Let $F,K$ be subfields of $\mathbb{C}$. Suppose that $t,\rho\in \mathbb{C}$ are algebraic over $F$ and $\rho \in K$. If $F(t)\cap K\subset F$, is it true that $F(t,\rho)\cap K\subset F(\rho)$? Any counterexample or any extra conditions to make it true?

This question rises up in an elementary (i.e. without Galois theory) proof of Abel-Ruffini theorem given by A. Skopenkov (See arXiv:1508.03317v4). I believe that there is a gap in the proof of theorem 4 in the article and we actually need to answer the question above, which seems not trivial.

I notice that $\sum f_i(t)\rho^i\in K$ does not imply $f_i(t)\in K$, so I feel that the answer is negative. But I can not provide any counterexample.